# react-native npm start gives Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: react-native, npm-start

I keep getting the below error ,when my react-native comes error in below screen, the moment react-native app is loaded in emulator.

```
npm start
```

error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:720:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:430:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:476:19)
    at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (/home/u/Documents/coding/p/gitlab/c/p/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:347:17)
    at new UnableToResolveError (/home/u/Documents/coding/p/gitlab/c/p/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:333:35)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/u/Documents/coding/p/gitlab/c/p/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/u/Documents/coding/p/gitlab/c/p/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
    at /home/u/Documents/coding/p/gitlab/c/p/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:317:42
    at /home/u/Documents/coding/p/gitlab/c/p/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1471:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: have you recently changed the npm config?

Comment: @Lukas no i have not